# Parse out word between two characters SQL Netezza

Tags: sql, netezza

I am having trouble finding the correct syntax to parse out a word between two characters in Netezza.

| PATIENT_NAME |
| --- |
| SMITH,JOHN L |
| BROWN,JANE R |
| JONES,MARY LYNN |

I need the first name which is always after the comma and before the first space. How would I do this in Netezza?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Netezza supports `regexp_extract()`.  That would be:

```
select replace(regexp_extract(name, ',[^ ]+'), ',', '')
```

Or `regexp_replace()`:

```
select regexp_replace(name, '^[^,]+,([^ ]+)( |$).*$', '\1')
```

Comment: This first one worked great. What is the  ',[^ ]+' doing in this expression?

Comment: That matches a subexpression that starts with a comma and is then followed by one or more non-space characters.

Answer (score 1):

Netezza supports `regexp_extract` and if there is reason to handle all kinds of whitespace between first and middle name(s) then this would work -

```sql
select regexp_extract(name,
    '^[^[:space:],]+[[:space:],]+([^[:space:]]+)')
```

This would handle optional whitespaces, tabs etc on either side of `,` as well.